# printf error invalid number

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to use a bash script that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                   
rm test
echo -e "0.3333232331313e+04" >> test
echo -e "5.564" >> test
echo -e "5.32312e+08" >> test
while read line; do
    var1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1;}')
    var2=$(printf "%.8e" $var1)
done < test
```

as far as i understand it, it simply write my numbers in a different format. But when i use it it returns these errors:

```
./test.sh: line 10: printf: 0.3333232331313e+04: nombre non valable
./test.sh: line 10: printf: 5.564: nombre non valable
./test.sh: line 10: printf: 5.32312e+08: nombre non valable
```

I also used to use this script in a different situation and it was working just fine. What does the error mean and can anyone point me to a tutorial of these characters (.8e , % ) thanks.

Comment: What version of bash do you have, because I cannot recreate those errors.  As an aside, you don't need the subshell for the var2 assignment, nor does my bash need to use `awk` to strip off the white space.  I can just do `printf -v var2 '%.8e' "$line"`

Comment: Yes, you are right seems like the putting LC_NUMERIC = C solves the problem. Thank you